# alphabetic sorting puts shorter string after longer string in error

Tags: php, usort

when sorting my array of strings, usort is putting the shorter string before the longer one, this is in odds to other sort methods, specifically the one on the client side of my app. for example. 'test' will come before 'test1'. how can i amend the sort such that the shorter string will appear after the longer one

i've devised a method which can find the shorter string but i can't seem to change the position of the sort

```
   usort($nc, function ($item1, $item2) use($sortcol){
                        $string1 = trim(strtolower($item1[$sortcol]));
                        $string2 = trim(strtolower($item2[$sortcol]));
                        if (strpos($string1, $string2) === 0 ) {

                                return 1;
                            }
                        if (strpos($string2, $string1) === 0 ) {

                                return -1;
                            }

                        return $string1 < $string2;
```

Comment: `return strcmp($string1, $string2)`…?!

Comment: please may you expand on this?

Comment: @BenKemp, strcmp is a native function that already compares two strings and returns an integer.

Comment: its the native function that thinks that the shorter string goes first alphabetically and so it doesn't solve my issue. looking for a workaround that follows the sorting behaviour of javascript. Thanks for a quick response though

Comment: Something else at work? IME "_sorting behaviour of javascript._" is the same as PHP sort  (ie 'test','test1')

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function doesn't make sense.

First, understand that when you compare strings with comparison operators (>, < and =), PHP is converting the characters in those strings to their ordinal values and then making numerical comparisons, not lexicographic. The reason "b" < "t" is because really PHP is comparing integers. This produces results you may not necessarily expect:

```
php > $one = "a"; $two = "b";
php > var_dump(strcmp($one, $two));
int(-1)
php > $one = "b"; $two = "a";
php > var_dump(strcmp($one, $two));
int(1)
php > $one = "b"; $two = "b";
php > var_dump(strcmp($one, $two));
int(0)
php > $one = "a"; $two = "z";
php > var_dump(strcmp($one, $two));
int(-25)
php > $one = "z"; $two = "a";
php > var_dump(strcmp($one, $two));
int(25)
php > $one = "aa"; $two = "z";
php > var_dump(strcmp($one, $two));
int(-25)
php > $one = "zz"; $two = "a";
php > var_dump(strcmp($one, $two));
int(25)
```

Using comparison operators to judge strings follows this same behavior so it's 100% expected given what's in your callback function. I'm not sure why you're checking to see if one is a substring of the other. If you want to check lengths first, check them, but understand that you're reversing the existing PHP convention of short strings before long; our first two return values reflect that change.

```
$result = usort($nc, function ($item1, $item2) use($sortcol){
    $string1 = trim(strtolower($item1[$sortcol]));
    $string2 = trim(strtolower($item2[$sortcol]));
    if (strlen($string1) > strlen($string2) ) {return -1;}
    if (strlen($string1) < strlen($string2) ) {return 1;}
    return $string1 < $string2;
});
```